# Checking for abnormal socket termination

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing a server with a session thread for an open connection to the client.  It's fairly simple, it just uses a buffered reader to read lines from the input.  If the line equals a special value that indicates the user wants to quit, or if it's null, the loop terminates.  Otherwise the message gets passed up the chain to the module that's meant to deal with it.  For the purposes of testing I'm simply telnetting to my server and manually entering commands.

This if fine, unless I terminate the connection by a way other than typing QUIT, for example by closing the terminal window.  Then a message with an unknown sequence of characters is generated and a malformed message gets passed up the chain.  In this simple test case it doesn't matter too much, but it does indicate a problem that needs to be addressed.

My code is as follows.

```
    public void run () {
        BufferedReader  inReader;
        UpstreamMessage message;
        String          lastLine;

        Thread.currentThread ().setName ("UpstreamThread_" + outer.getId ());

        try {
            inReader    = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (outer.clientSocket.getInputStream (), "UTF8"));
            while (!this.ending) {
                // Read whatever was in the input buffer
                lastLine    = inReader.readLine ();
                Logger.getLogger (this.getClass ().getName ()).log (Level.INFO, "Last data from input stream reader was \"{0}\"", lastLine);
                if (null != lastLine && !lastLine.equals ("QUIT")) {
                    message = new UpstreamMessage (outer.sessionId, lastLine);
                    outer.server.acceptMessage (message);
                } else {
                    // End the session
                    Logger.getLogger (this.getClass ().getName ()).log (Level.INFO, "Thread ending");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger (this.getClass ().getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage (), ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // This is thrown when we're telling the thread to shut down so it's normal
            Logger.getLogger (this.getClass ().getName ()).log (Level.INFO, ex.getMessage (), ex);
        } finally {
            this.terminate ();
        }
    }
```

When I close my terminal window, my console outputs the following for the logging:

> Jul 27, 2013 7:37:00 PM bikeshop.server.Session$UpstreamChannel run
>   INFO: Last data from input stream reader was
>   "        "

Or sometimes, the logger reports the following, suggesting that the lastMessage variable references a null, but the null check fails.

> Jul 27, 2013 7:37:00 PM bikeshop.server.Session$UpstreamChannel run
>   INFO: Last data from input stream reader was "null"

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't know what.  My test, 'if (null != lastLine && !lastLine.equals ("QUIT"))' is not catching whatever ends up in the buffer when I quit the terminal.  How do I handle this case more gracefully?

EDIT: More careful analysis of the logs and single-step debugging revealed that what happens is that the telnet client sends a sequence of control characters when you quit it.  This gets read from the buffer and passed up the chain, triggering warnings in other parts of my program.  Then the session goes through its loop again and tries to read from the now closed socket.  This does return null and the loop terminates.  This is what the source of confusion over whether or not the last line read from the client was null.  The last thing read was indeed null, but it was the penultimate read that was the important one, the one that was triggering the anomalous behaviour.

So I guess the question has changed to either a) What control sequence does a telnet client send when you quit it, or b) does Java know how to check for that control sequence?

Comment: `readLine()` returns `null` if the socket is closed as per the docs. Your `if` statement's first condition as shown will see that (or, your computer is broken ;) ). If your logging says "null" and it's not ... then the string contains the actual text "null". Put it in the debugger and step through, you will see what's going on.

Comment: I've done that, the variable watch says that when you quit the terminal you get a string of characters in the last readline.  They seem to be non-printable characters so I get a string of spaces displayed in the logging and in the debugger.  Obviously a string of non-printable characters is not null and the wrong branch is taken

Comment: second note: telnet is _not_ a "raw" socket protocol.  it's does extra stuff which may not be want you want.  use a real test client, _not_ telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(decided to move this to an answer)

`BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` if the socket is closed as per the docs. Your if statement's first condition as shown:

```
if (null != lastLine && !lastLine.equals ("QUIT"))
```

will evaluate to `false` if that is the case (or, your computer is broken ;) ).

If your logging says "null" and it's not evaluating to `false` ... then the string contains the actual text "null". Put it in the debugger, set a breakpoint in this loop, and step through looking at the value of `lastLine`; you will see what's going on.

That said, the first rule of writing a server is *never trust the client*. Like in the case of your using telnet ultimately you don't have any control over what's being sent to you.

When you read from that socket, you need to be doing more input validation so you don't attempt to process something that isn't valid. How you approach that will vary but the usual solutions are a `Map` of valid commands, a regex that validates the input structure, etc. Not doing this results in a very fragile piece of server software, which you've discovered.

Comment: I'm using a telnet client to debug.  It seems that when you quit it it sends a sequence of control characters.  Those characters aren't null or QUIT so they get sent up the chain and the server goes around its loop one more time.  When it goes through that loop reading from the buffer does return null and the loop ends.  That's why it looked like I was getting a null in the logging but failing the test.

Comment: I understand that. The point being, *there's nothing you can do about what is being sent to you*. I edited to expand on the input validation part - you need to look for things that aren't what you expect before just sending the input on.

Comment: @GordonM Brian is spot-on here. If you can't cope with the extra stuff that Telnet sends on termination, either don't use Telnet as the client, or implement the Telnet protocol at the server so you can understand it.